# Domain expired, want to transfer registrars. Will the domain be unavailable for the 5 day transfer duration?

Tags: domains, domain-registrar

I've been slowly moving my domains over to a new registrar just as they're about to expire. I let a couple expire by accident and now there's no DNS of course. If I begin the transfer process will DNS be unavailable until the transfer is complete?

Answer (score 2):

Yes.  But more than that.  You aren't even going to be able to transfer registrar once it has expired.  You are going to have to renew them in place and then transfer.

Comment: Short, sweet, and very precise answer!

Comment: I believe it **can** be transferred - [Yes. You can transfer an expired domain name if it is still in the registrar's renewal grace period. Grace periods differ by registrar and domain name extension. However, once the status indicates that the domain name is in registry redemption, you can no longer transfer it.](http://support.godaddy.com/help/article/6870/domain-name-transfer-faq)

Comment: @javy - I am happy to be corrected, but my experience as a reseller is that I have never been able to transfer a domain that is in transfer or has expired.